# Outlook 2007 on WIndows 7 unable to send attachments and emails over a few kb in size

Tags: windows-7, outlook-2007

using pop email, any email larger than a few kb in size and/or with an attachment will not send.  The Outlook error message lists 'server timeout' or 'unable to connect to outgoing server' as the issue.  No one else is having this issue, all server settings are correct, I have removed and recreated the profile, updated Windows, experimented with different settings.

This is a new laptop.  The PST came from an XP machine running Office 2007.

Google has nothing for me.  I am hoping that you guys do.

Please ask questions if I need to be more specific.  I am not sure what else to include.

laptop is a Dell Latitude E6510 running Windows 7 Enterprise.  Office 2007.  McAfee 8.7i (which I have disabled).

Comment: what kind of email server is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be due to a Microsoft network setting.  Review the following article for more information:

**It takes much longer than expected to download an e-mail message from a POP3 server in Outlook 2007 or in Outlook 2010**

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/935400

Comment: THANK YOU!!!  I followed the instructions in the article under 'fix it myself' and the issue is resolved.  I have worked on this for 2 days!!  The user was very frustrated, being unable to send attachments was crippling.  thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can try increasing the time out timer. Your internet connection might be to slow.
You can find this here: extra -> email account settings -> select your account and click edit-> click more settings in bottom right corner -> click advanced tab, this is the last one.
(this might be a bad translation from the dutch office)

Comment: thanks...will try.  We have 15mb fiber connection here.  I almost feel like its a Windows 7 connectivity issue and not an Outlook issue, but will give it a try.